# Google font is not working on ngx-stripe package on angular project

Tags: angular, stripe-payments, ngx-stripe

`In CheckoutComponent.html

````
 <ngx-stripe-card-group [elementsOptions]="elementsOptions">
    <ngx-stripe-card-number [options]="cardOptions" class="stripe-input"></ngx-stripe-card-number>
    <ngx-stripe-card-expiry [options]="cardOptions" class="stripe-input"></ngx-stripe-card-expiry>
    <ngx-stripe-card-cvc [options]="cardOptions" class="stripe-input"></ngx-stripe-card-cvc>
  </n`your text`gx-stripe-card-group>



In CheckoutComponent.ts
  import { StripeService, StripeCardComponent, StripeCardNumberComponent } from 'ngx-stripe';
  import { StripeCardElementOptions, StripeElementsOptions, PaymentIntent, loadStripe,       StripeAddressElementOptions } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

  @ViewChild(StripeCardNumberComponent) card!: StripeCardNumberComponent;

  public cardOptions: StripeCardElementOptions = {
    
```
style: {
      base: {
        // fontWeight: 400,
        fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
        fontSize: '14px',
        iconColor: '#666EE8',
        color: 'rgba(0,0,0,.88)',
        '::placeholder': {
          color: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25)'
        },
      },
    },
  };
  public elementsOptions: StripeElementsOptions = {
    locale: 'en',`your text`
  };
````

Comment: not sure if you have already checked any warnings/errors on the console. Also, if possible, please share a sample working code,it will be easy for us to assist.